# it's impossible to choose layout for page on print preview in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I've got a page on website with a lot of data, svg elements.
  When I press Ctrl+P in Chrome and look at it - the page on preview displayed without any layout (portrait or landscape). I even can't choose it, because there is no option for it. In FF it's looks fine.
  I know about media queries and know that i can write this:

> @page{size: portrait}

ok, now it looks better, but user still can not choose layout.
  I have read something about that it can be depends on width and browser can't correctly calculate it, is it true? How can i resolve this issue? On my page i've used bootstrap grid layout.

Comment: i was close...     @page{size: auto}